# How to get specific items in Microsoft Graph´s JSON response

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api

Hello I am using Microsoft Graph with OneNote and when I make the following request : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/pages?$select=title,links

[I get this response:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Bzwc.png)

I don´t need the "oneNoteClientUrl" attribute, so How can I get only the "oneNoteWebUrl" attribute.

And when I use:  pages? search=item&select=title,links.
I get this issue.

{
    "error": {
        "code": "10002",
        "message": "The service is currently unavailable. Please try again later.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "13535682-a12b-4127-935b-6601154c1416",
            "date": "2017-05-31T21:38:04"
        }
    }
}

I read that "search is available for consumer notebooks only"

How can I get pages with specific words in their content and title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the API doesn't yet support searching pages in SharePoint - only in OneDrive consumer. This is something in our radar, but we don't yet have any ETA on this.

I encourage you to create/upvote a uservoice entry for this.
https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis

Comment: To answer your first question - you selected title and links. The links property is a complex type with multiple properties - so all the properties in the complex type are returned.  Not sure if $select can support selecting at multiple levels.

Comment: @Jorge Aguirre, that uservoice link is broken, where do we file requests now? Is there already one created for this?

Comment: @Jorge Aguire is it already fixed?